# Embed FB page plugin inside Instant Article

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-like

May I know how to embed **FB page plugin** inside **Instant Article**, I try to search related topics online, but found none. It seems that I can't include any Javascript in Instant Article, thus I can't use the page plugin Js code generated with [Facebook developer](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin).

However, I notice that there are users who can embed the FB page plugin to their Instant Article, may I know how they do it?

**Note:** They are including a "*real*" FB page plugin, not an image with `<a href="...">`, the "Like Page" and "Share" are functional...

[image]

I am using Wordpress Instant Article plugin, however, I am fine with any custom solution.

Anyone? Please help.

Comment: They probably just used the iframe code directly ...

Comment: how to insert a page iframe in Instant Article? How about the height, width, etc? Do you know the implementation? Thanks... :D